# Why doesn't Doctrine 2 find my entities?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to learn about using [Doctrine 2](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) by making a very simple script which fetches information from my database. The problem is that I can't find any documentation explaining how Doctrine finds and uses my mapping entities. And so when it complains that it's not finding an entity, I don't know what to do to solve the problem. Consider the following structure in my www folder:

- Doctrine/
- Entities/
- - person.php
- myTestPage.php

**person.php**

```
<?php

/** @Entity @Table(name="person")*/
class person
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $uid;
}
?>
```

**myTestPage.php**

```
<?php
    require "Doctrine/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Setup.php";

    $lib = "Doctrine";
    Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup::registerAutoloadDirectory($lib);

    use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup,
        Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

    $paths = array("/Entities");

    $isDevMode = true;

    $dbParams = array("driver" => "pdo_mysql",
        "host" => "myhost.ca",
        "user" => "Shawn",
        "password" => "noneofyourbusiness",
        "dbname" => "testDB");

    $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
    $em = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select(array('uid'))
        ->from('person', 't');
    $query = $qb->getQuery();

    $result = $query->getResult();
    echo $result;
?>
```

When I visit myTestPage.php, I get the following error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException'
>   with message '[Semantical Error] line 0, col 24 near 'person':
>   Error: Class 'person' is not defined.' in
>   C:\wamp\www\Doctrine\Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException.php on line 47

The problem seems to be that Doctrine can't find person.php, but how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't exactly know what the "re1_chercheur" means, but when I tried your code, it complained about person not being defined, so i included that and it worked. 
Of course, this should be dealt with by using an autoloader of some sort, but I think doctrine has some solution for that also. I haven't been using their autoloader, because I have my own which uses the PSR compliant autoloading.

Also in your select, if you want just the "uid", use "t.uid". "t" is the alias of the person class, so in other places in the query, you'll be using "t" to get to it's properties (you could do a ->where("t.uid = someNumber")). If you want the whole object use select("t");

I found the [doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/index.html) quite helpful, just make sure you go in the order it is laid out, and you'll get the hang of it in no time.

I know this is not an exact answer, but maybe it points you into the right direction.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change the table name in the error message, it should say `person` (I changed it now). When I manually `require "Entities/person.php";`, the error message changes and says that uid is not defined. Then, I add `t.` before the table name and now everything works. So you were right all the way. The autoloader is not working, and I can get around that problem by manually requiring the class file. I would like to know why the autoloader doesn't work though...

Comment: I do not know about doctrine's autoloader, since I use my own, but as I said, their documentation is pretty clear and with good examples, so you should have no trouble going through that.

Comment: Actually I did have some trouble. I re-installed Doctrine with PEAR and now I got it to work using `Setup::registerAutoloadPEAR(); $cl = new Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Entities', __DIR__); $cl->register();`

Comment: Glad you got it working. Sorry I couldn't help with the loader, but I was not really comfortable giving advice about it, since I've never actually used it